# How to connect to locally synced node of polkadot

Tags: substrate-node-template

I've setup the full node of polkadot westend network and it's fully synced now I want to connect with my node on local host how could I do that

Comment: Could you select an answer if any one of them answers your question?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of different ways to connect.

You can connect using [polkadotJS apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps).

You can also use [polkadotsJS api](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api) and connect with your node using JavaScript.

Lots of resources on connecting to your node here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials

You can also use [substrate-api-sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar) to build a REST api around your node and interact with your node in a REST fashion.

Answer (score 1):

As Bruno mentioned there are multiple ways to connect to a node but it also depends on what you would like to achieve when connecting to your node.

For example there is also another tool called [subxt](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt) which is a Rust library for interacting with a substrate based node. If your goal is to do one of the following :

- Accessing storage entries
- Accessing constants
- Subscribing to events
- Submitting extrinsics

you could also use this tool.

Last, another resource worth checking is our Polkadot wiki page regarding [Node Interaction](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-node-interaction) which mentions different ways to interact with your node and showing some examples.

Comment: Actually I've started my node with this commad
polkadot --chain=westend and in my code I've done this

ry:
    substrate = SubstrateInterface(
               url="http://localhost:9933/",
        # url="http://127.0.0.1:9933/",
        type_registry_preset="substrate-node-template"
    )
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    print("⚠️ No local Substrate node running, try running 'start_local_substrate_node.sh' first")
    exit()

and after that I'm finding my account's balance  request it's showing 0 but my account's balance is'nt 0